# Python regex to find specific word in the middle of a text file

Tags: python, regex, grouping

I have a text file basically and I want to search for the middle word of a sentence. I get an error saying `found_state not defined` when I run my `.py` script.

Consider this file:

```
file.conf
hostname(config)#aaa new-model
fdfsfd b
kthik
pooooo
shh
```

My python script looks like:

```
import re;    
import time;

with open('file.conf') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
name=''

for data in content:
    if re.search('(?<=#)\w+',data):
        found_state=1
        name=data
        break
if found_state==1:
    print name + "is Found"
else:
    print "NF"
```

Comment: So, declare `found_state` beforehand. Where do you use the script? Besides declaring the variable first, you might need to also specify `global found_state` inside the `if` block, and then assign  it to `1`.

Comment: Ok, perhaps, all you need is `r'#(\w+)'` and then `.group(1)`? See https://ideone.com/HdPCEt

Comment: Improved formatting a little

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you say you need to get the "middle word" I understand you need to *extract* that word. Right now, you get the whole line if there is a match.

Here is [a piece of code](https://ideone.com/HdPCEt) that should work for you (it prints `aaa is Found`):

```
import re;
content = ["hostname(config)#aaa new-model", "fdfsfd b", "kthik", "pooooo", "shh"] # <= TEST DATA
name=''
found_state = 0                       # Declare found_state
for data in content:
    m = re.search(r'#(\w+)',data)     # Use a raw string literal and a capturing group
    if m:                             # Check if there was a match and if yes
        found_state=1                 #   - increment found_state
        name=m.group(1)               #   - get the word after #
        break
if found_state==1:
    print name + " is Found"
else:
    print "NF"
```

However, perhaps, you'd want to reduce your code to

```
res = []
for data in content:
    res.extend(re.findall(r'#(\w+)', data))
print(res)
```

See [this demo](https://ideone.com/GznnZP). The `#(\w+)` pattern will capture word chars (1 or more) after a `#`, and will only return these captured substrings and `extend` will add all them to the list.

Answer (score 0):

If your condition `if re.search('(?<=#)\w+',data):` fails, then found_state is not declared. Do that before the for loop.

Comment: what should be the regex to find #aaa inside the text file then?

Comment: am getting none output on running the python script can somebody guide me with particular regex?